# htaccess - redirect directory but not sub directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to create a .htaccess redirect file that redirects all traffic from an old domain (olddomain.com/feedback/) to a new domain (newdomain.com).  However i do not want traffic to redirect traffic to olddomain.com/feedback/form/customer-feedback/ and wish for that to still go to the original destination.

Here is what i have created to date.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/feedback/form/customer-feedback
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost perfect.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^feedback/form/customer-feedback
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

On the second line, I have removed the slash immediately preceding `feedback/`.

When you compose `mod_rewrite` directives, whatever follows the start-of-match indicator `^` is what comes *after* the immediately preceding slash in the URI.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in old server's root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^feedback/?$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```